# Appstats In Unit Tests (Java)

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I'm using JUnit for our Google AppEngine application unit testing.  Is there some way I can get the equivalent of what [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) provides, but within a unit test?  I'd like to see how many reads/writes to the datastore an individual test consumes, and assert on a limit to assure our code remains tight and efficient.

I've searched endlessly at stackoverflow and Google, either no one has asked **and answered** this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054339/how-to-use-appstats-with-junit-tests-google-app-engine) or I can't seem to come up with the right set of words.

**This is for Java, NOT Python** (which appears to have a facility for this sort of thing)